# Authorization, tokens and nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, security, jwt

I’m thinking about authorization for my app. Beyond JWT authentication against a mongo database, i'd like to secure certain routes for different roles. I’m not interested in OAuth or 3rd party services

What I’m having difficulty with is where to store role. If I query database for authentication and return a token, should I also return the role in the payload? Then check with middleware once authenticated if the user is further authorized? Can’t someone rewrite the token with admin privileges ?

**What’s the standard way for doing this?**

This is ultimately and api serving an angular app on the front end

Thanks

Comment: A JWT is signed, so if the token is edited, the hash will no longer match, and the token can be rejected. That check can only really be made in the backend / APIs though. There is very little in terms of security that can be done from a SPA

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to do this using a `JWT signed token`  which is signed by a private key from the server generated on it and a public key is sent over to all the consuming clients.If, anyone changes the body within the token the **authenticating authority** which is the server will try to digitally verify the signature through its private key . Since, this token is different to the one sent over by signing from the server , the signatures will never match.

Also, to protect your `JWT token` to be sniffed out as a part of alive session you put up [CSRF/XSRF](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3312) mitigation strategy in place

Comment: Thanks. I guess I’m more concerned with the process of having roles added to the structure of the app. Not just authentication but also authorization. Specific people able to hit certain endpoints